# SphinxSE with MariaDB not returning result

Tags: mariadb, sphinx

I am using MariaDB 10.1.19 and Sphinx 2.2.10

I am trying to query the Sphinx server using SphinxSE plugin available in MariaDB but I'm getting "OK" as response instead of result (rows).

Query : `SELECT * FROM from_sphinx_documents Where query ="eml";`

[Screenshot of Database Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOdq1.png)

I validated Sphinx server by querying it using test jar file and I'm able to get the result there.

[Query from command Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGvpA.png)

Below is the structure of my Proxy Table :

```
CREATE TABLE from_sphinx_documents( 
   id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
   weight INTEGER NOT NULL, 
   query VARCHAR(3072) NOT NULL, 
   group_id INTEGER,    
   _sph_count  INTEGER, 
   CASE_ID INTEGER, 
   FOLDER_ID INTEGER, 
   DOC_ID INTEGER, 
   INDEX(query)
) ENGINE=SPHINX CONNECTION ="sphinx://10.0.10.150:9675/documents"
```

Please can anybody shed a light on it. Is it a version mismatch issue ?

Comment: Just a guess, but you seem to have used uppercase for the attributes, but can see in screenshot they are lowercase. Sphinx tends to like attributes in lowercase. Also `group_id` is an example attribute in the documentation, you dont have one of your own, maybe you meant `_sph_groupby` ?

Comment: Ah, also did you check `SHOW ENGINE SPHINX STATUS` ?

Comment: oh, and docs also says "must have a types of INTEGER UNSINGED or BIGINT for the 1st column (document id)" (sic), BIGint is not unsigned

Comment: @barryhunter I am using the above configuration files in another QA environment and it's working fine there. SHOW ENGINE SPHINX STATUS is not returning any result. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD8Hw.png)

 Whereas SPHINX is listed in result of SHOW ENGINES.

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/172cy.png)